# Grunt bump and prompt for commit message

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt but I'm trying to combine [grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump/%22grunt-bump%22) with [grunt-prompt](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt) so that the user is prompted to enter a commit message which is then added to the commit.

I've based the code in my Gruntfile.js from [this post](https://eedle.com/2014/10/09/using-grunt-prompt-with-grunt-git/) but the prompt element isn't working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bump');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prompt');

  grunt.initConfig({
    prompt: {
    commit: {
      options: {
        questions: [{
                   config: 'gitmessage',
                   type: 'input',
                   message: 'Commit Message'
                   }]
        }
      }
    },
    bump: {
    options: {
      files: ['package.json'],
      updateConfigs: [],
      commit: true,
      commitMessage: '<%=grunt.config("prompt.gitmessage")%>',
      commitFiles: ['package.json'],
      createTag: true,
      tagName: 'v%VERSION%',
      tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%',
      push: true,
      pushTo: 'origin',
      gitDescribeOptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d',
      globalReplace: false,
      prereleaseName: false,
      metadata: '',
      regExp: false
    }
  },
  });

};
```

and this is the terminal output:

```
$ grunt bump
Running "bump" task
>> Version bumped to 7.0.39 (in package.json)
>> Committed as " v7.0.39"
>> Tagged as "v7.0.39"
>> Pushed to origin

Done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution A:

You need to make a couple of changes to your `Gruntfile.js` as shown in the following example *(See comments 1 and 2)*:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bump');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prompt');

  grunt.initConfig({

    prompt: {
      commit: {
        options: {
          questions: [{
            config: 'gitmessage',
            type: 'input',
            message: 'Commit Message'
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    bump: {
      options: {
        files: ['package.json'],
        updateConfigs: [],
        commit: true,
        commitMessage: '<%=grunt.config("gitmessage")%>',// 1) Change this.
        commitFiles: ['package.json'],
        createTag: true,
        tagName: 'v%VERSION%',
        tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%',
        push: true,
        pushTo: 'origin',
        gitDescribeOptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d',
        globalReplace: false,
        prereleaseName: false,
        metadata: '',
        regExp: false
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('myBump', ['prompt:commit', 'bump']);// 2) Register new task.
}
```

---

**Notes**

1. Firstly, change your value of the `commitMessage` property in your `bump` Task to the following:

   ```js
   '<%=grunt.config("gitmessage")%>'
   ```

   The `prompt.` part you currently have in your [grunt template](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) has been omitted. It should be the value of the `config` property you specify in your `prompt` task only.
2. Next, register a new Task, let's call it `myBump`. I.e.

   ```js
   grunt.registerTask('myBump', ['prompt:commit', 'bump']);
   ```

   ***Important:** You can choose another name for the task instead of `myBump`, however it cannot be named `bump` as it will conflict with the existing task.*

   This newly registered task ensures the `prompt:commit` task is run before the `bump` by doing the following:

   - [Alias Tasks](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) the `commit` [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) of your `prompt` task (i.e. `prompt:commit`).
   - Then aliases the `bump` task.

---

**Running the Task**

Instead of running `grunt bump` via your CLI you'll need to run; `grunt myBump`.

Running `grunt myBump` via your CLI will:

1. Firstly prompt you to enter your commit message. For example:

   > `Running "prompt:commit" (prompt) task`
   >
   > `? Commit Message` **My message about the bump**
2. Then subsequently runs your `bump` task. For example::

   > `Running "bump" task`
   >
   > `>> Version bumped to 1.0.1 (in package.json)`
   >
   > `>> Committed as` **My message about the bump**
   >
   > `>> Tagged as "v1.0.1"`

---

### Solution B:

Whilst *Solution A* works fine it doesn't accommodate bumping all the [semver](https://semver.org/) versions. It currently only bumps the `PATCH` version each time `grunt myBump` is run.

Perhaps, your intention is to enable a way to handle various types of semver bumps. Which are categorized as follows:

- > **MAJOR** version when you make incompatible API changes,
- > **MINOR** version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner,
- > **PATCH** version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

The following `Gruntfile.js` shows a configuration for handling either of the version types listed above.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bump');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prompt');

  grunt.initConfig({

    prompt: {
      patch: {
        options: {
          questions: [{
            config: 'gitmessage',
            type: 'input',
            message: 'Commit message for PATCH version bump:'
          }]
        }
      },
      minor: {
        options: {
          questions: [{
            config: 'gitmessage',
            type: 'input',
            message: 'Commit message for MINOR version bump:'
          }]
        }
      },
      major: {
        options: {
          questions: [{
            config: 'gitmessage',
            type: 'input',
            message: 'Commit message for MAJOR version bump:'
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    bump: {
      options: {
        files: ['package.json'],
        updateConfigs: [],
        commit: true,
        commitMessage: '<%=grunt.config("gitmessage")%>',
        commitFiles: ['package.json'],
        createTag: true,
        tagName: 'v%VERSION%',
        tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%',
        push: true,
        pushTo: 'origin',
        gitDescribeOptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d',
        globalReplace: false,
        prereleaseName: false,
        metadata: '',
        regExp: false
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('bump-patch', ['prompt:patch', 'bump:patch']);
  grunt.registerTask('bump-minor', ['prompt:minor', 'bump:minor']);
  grunt.registerTask('bump-major', ['prompt:major', 'bump:major']);
}
```

**Running**

Using the configuration shown above you run the following commands via your CLI as appropriate:

- To bump the `PATCH` version run:

  ```
  grunt bump-patch
  ```
- To bump the `MINOR` version run:

  ```
  grunt bump-minor
  ```
- To bump the `MAJOR` version run:

  ```
  grunt bump-major
  ```

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you so much for taking the time to respond in such detail. I went with solution B which is working perfectly.